# Give syntax proof of $\forall x (P(x) \lor Q(x))$ , $\forall y. \neg P(y)$ $\vdash$ $\forall x.Q(x)$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, first-order-logic, natural-deduction

[image]So the question is in the title already. I have to prove the following using first-order logic but I am failing to do so. Please someone help me understand how do I do it?

$\forall x (P(x) \lor Q(x))$ , $\forall y. \neg P(y)$ $\vdash$ $\forall x.Q(x)$

Comment: You must make an argument using natural deduction, sequent calculi, or through axioms... or show that there isn't a counterexample with a semantic tableaux.

Comment: There's no standard set of axioms for FOL, so you need to specify yours.

Comment: @Sam I have attached the picture. Kindly see that is all I have.

Answer (score 2):

$$\forall x (P(x) \lor Q(x)) , \forall y. \neg P(y) \vdash \forall x.Q(x)$$

Start at the end. Keeping an eye on where you want to go will help you get there.

---

$\dfrac{A}{\forall x~.A[x\backslash t]}{\forall\mathsf{intro}}$ means that when given a predicate you may generalise to a universal by replacing all instances of the *arbitrary free variable* with a bound variable *that does not occur free in the original predicate*.

Your consequent is such a universal statement, so you will want this on the bottom of your proof (ie: the root of the tree).

$$\dfrac{~~\vdots\\Q(t)}{\forall x~Q(x)}{\forall\mathsf{intro}}$$

Now we know where to go, let us look at where we start.

---

$\dfrac{\forall x~.A}{A[t\backslash x]}{\forall\textsf{elim}}$ means that "when given a universal statement, we may infer the predicate with all instances of the bound variable replaced with a free variable."

In your premise of $\forall x~.(P(x)\lor Q(x)$ the predicate is $P(x)\lor Q(x)$ and bound variable is $x$, so the replacement of that with free variable $t$ is: $P(t)\lor Q(t)$.

In your other premise of $\forall y~.\lnot P(x)$ the predicate is $\lnot P(y)$ and bound variable is $y$, so the replacement of that with (the same) free variable $t$ is: $\lnot P(t)$.

So you will be using both of these.

$$\dfrac{~\forall x~.(P(x)\lor Q(x))~}{P(t)\vee Q(t)}{\forall\mathsf{elim}}\qquad\dfrac{\forall y~.\lnot P(y)}{\lnot P(t)}{\forall\mathsf{elim}}$$

These will occur in the undischarged leaves of your tree.

There will possibly be other leaves--which must be discharged assumptions--and the branches will need to be built between these and the root.

One of the things we may derive is a disjunction.  So let us seek the rules for *eliminating* this.

---

$\dfrac{\lower{1.5ex}{A\vee B}~~\dfrac{[A]\\~~\vdots}{C}~~\dfrac{[B]\\~~\vdots}{C}}{C}{\vee\mathsf{elim}}$ means that when given a derivation of $A\vee B$, a derivation of $C$ from assumed $A$ and a derivation of $C$ from assumed $B$, then we may infer $C$ (and discharge those assumptions).

You have a derivation for $P(t)\vee Q(t)$, you wish to derive $Q(t)$, so you shall need to derive it from assumptions.  Well, $Q(t)$ is trivially derived when you assume it, so that leaves deriving it from $P(t)$.

$$\dfrac{\dfrac{~\vdots~}{P(t)\vee Q(t)}\quad\dfrac{[P(t)]^1\\~~\vdots}{Q(t)}\quad\lower{1.5ex}{[Q(t)]^2}}{Q(t)}{\vee\mathsf{elim}^{1,2}}$$

But how?   Wait, there is also the other premise, from which we may derive $\lnot P(t)$.   So, let us take a look at the rules using negation.

---

$\dfrac{A~~\lnot A}{\bot}{\lnot\mathsf{elim}}$ means that when given derivations of a predicate and its negation we may infer the contradiction constant (also called *falsum* or *bottom*).

Okay, what can we do about that $\bot$ symbol?

---

$\dfrac{\bot}{B}{\bot\mathsf{elim}}$ means that whenever the contradiction constant is derived, then we may infer *any* predicate we may desire.   This is also known as the principle of explosion, or *ex falso quodlibet* (EFQ).

---

We look good to go!   You just need to stack it all it together.

$$\phantom{\tiny\dfrac{\dfrac{\dfrac{~\forall x~.(P(x)\lor Q(x))~}{P(t)\vee Q(t)}{\forall\mathsf{elim}}\quad\dfrac{\dfrac{\lower{1.5ex}{[P(t)]^1}\quad\dfrac{\forall y~.\lnot P(y)}{\lnot P(t)}{\forall\mathsf{elim}}}{\bot}{\lnot\mathsf{elim}}}{Q(t)}{\bot\mathsf{elim}}\quad\lower{1.5ex}{[Q(t)]^2}}{Q(t)}{\vee\mathsf{elim}^{1,2}}}{\forall x~.Q(x)}{\forall\mathsf{intro}^t}}$$

Comment: You have used a different method, I am unable to reach at conclusion by stacking every result. If you could do that part also, it will be much helpful for me.

Comment: How did you drive $Q(t)$ from $P(t)$. I am unable to understand it. Can you elaborate a bit further please

Comment: Oh I got it all finally. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

So as for the first rule of natural deduction you can only use the elimination of the universal quantifier; can you go on from there?

it is just like PL until (and not including) the last necessary rule.